# Magento: Problem with multistores theme

Tags: magento-1.9

Good morning,

I have a problem with Multistores in Magento, I've created a multi-shop, watches, up there all right, but would like to apply the same template that the main store to modify it to my tasteso I have duplicate files in the folder `app/design/frontend/mytheme/default` and `skin/frontend/mytheme/default` thus leaving:

- `app/design/frontend/mytheme/watches/`
- `app/design/frontend/mytheme/default`

---

- `skin/frontend/mytheme/watches`
- `skin/frontend/mytheme/default`

Then select the corresponding store, in this case watches and Design > Themes add the folder name watches in template, appearance, design and default.

The problem is that that modify the css from the `/mytheme/watches` folder still appear the styles of the main store, so I can not customize the watch shop without modifying the original.

Does anyone know how I can fix it? Thanks for everything, a greeting.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for translating! Could you also add a screenshot of the `System > Configuration > Design` page so we can see the settings?

Comment: For `Default` the value should always be *default* so it has a fallback to the original theme. This way you don't have to copy everything. As to why it edits the global scope settings when you change it on store level I'm not sure yet

Answer (score 0):

your `package` name will be `mytheme` so set it in package

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing tests and I've changed the name to maddox, now is so (not work)

- /public_html/app/design/frontend/maddox/default  (duplicate template)
- /public_html/app/design/frontend/sm-maxshop/default (original
  template)

---

- /public_html/skin/frontend/maddox/default (duplicate template)
- /public_html/skin/frontend/sm-maxshop/default (original
  template)